# How to Efficiently calculate the intersection of conjugacy classes of a normalizer.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3$). Let $$H=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}:b\in\mathbb{Z_3}\right\}.$$ Then $$N_G(H)=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0& d\end{bmatrix}:b\in\mathbb{Z_3} \text{ and } c,d\in\mathbb{Z_3^*}\right\}.$$ How do I efficiently compute $\bigcap_{x\in G} xN_G(H)x^{-1}$ ?

Comment: You mean $G=GL_2(\Bbb F_3)$?

Comment: Yes, let us go with that.

Comment: All right, I went with that.

Comment: So, how would I effiecently compute what I want to? I have already computed it by examining all options. It took me a whole day. But I want to know how to more effieciently compute it .